# Move entire tree to its leftChild and assign new tree to rightChild and change the root's node

Tags: c#, tree

I created a tree , but now (Inside the code) , I want to Move entire tree to its leftChild and assign a new tree to rightChild and change the root's node !
as shown in picture below:

[image]

In C# if it's possible.

Comment: Um, so do it. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. **Please see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.**

Comment: You need to show some code showing how you are representing a tree and what operations it currently supports.

Comment: Absolutely, it's possible in C#.  Show your work and tell us what went wrong, and hopefully we can find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

From your image I guess you're making a binary tree. All a tree is when you get down to it is a series of nodes.

So assuming you have a node class like this.

```
public class MyBinaryNode
{

    MyBinaryNode LeftChild;
    MyBinaryNode RightChild;

    MyBinaryNode() 
    {
        LeftChild = null;
        RightChild = null;
    }
    MyBinaryNode(MyBinaryNode leftChild, MyBinaryNode rightChild)
    {
        LeftChild = leftChild;
        RightChild = rightChild;
    }
}
```

All you'd have to do is something like this;

```
MyBinaryNode B = new MyBinaryNode();
MyBinaryNode C = new MyBinaryNode();

MyBinaryNode A = new MyBinaryNode(B,C); //This is your current tree

MyBinaryNode E = new MyBinaryNode();
MyBinaryNode D = new MyBinaryNode(A,E); //This is how you make the one in your Image
```

Comment: -1 for providing an (completely guesswork) answer to a terribly bad written question, thus encouraging the OP and other people to keep making such a bad quality type of questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh come on now @HighCore. This wasn't a well worded question but the image clearly shows a binary tree being added to another B-tree. I'm guessing English isn't this OP's first language and they obviously don't have any in depth command of C# either so I decided to give them a break and explain the concept of a Node to them. Is there anything wrong with my answer besides the fact that it's to a badly worded question? Down votes are for bad answers not good answers to bad questions.

Comment: the answer per-se is ok. But again, these type of questions should not be answered at all. Regardless if you understood what the OP is asking, we need to let them know that they `should` post the code they already tried, and a specific description of the problem at hand. `Gimme The Codez` type of questions are not welcome in SO.

Comment: @HighCore I can't say I disagree with your point about Gimme's but I didn't see it as something like that. I also feel that the correctness of my responding to the OP is something that should be discussed on Meta with links to this and merits a discussion.

Comment: I agree. This deserves a Meta discussion.

Comment: @HighCore Feel free to open a question and link it here please. So I'll be able join in on the talk. Thanks.

Comment: alright, based on [this Answer on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16622/252369) I removed the downvote.